# Add a table within a ggplot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would need help in order to add something like a geom_table within my figure.

Here is the figure I can produce :

[image]
Here is the code I used :

```
library(ggtree)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

tr <- rtree(30)
p <- ggtree(tr)
#df1<-dput(read.table("/Users/user/Desktop/test_data.txt",sep=";",h=T))
p1 <- p %<+% df1 + geom_tippoint(aes(color=location))
d2 <- data.frame(id=tr$tip.label, val=rnorm(30, sd=3))
p2 <- facet_plot(p1, panel="dot", data=d2, geom=geom_point, aes(x=val), color='firebrick') + theme_tree2()
d3 <- data.frame(id = rep(tr$tip.label, each=2),
                 value = abs(rnorm(60, mean=100, sd=50)),
                 category = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 30))
p3 <- facet_plot(p2, panel = 'Stacked Barplot', data = d3, 
                 geom = geom_barh, 
                 mapping = aes(x = value, fill = as.factor(category)), 
                 stat='identity' )
```

and I would like to know if there is a way to add a table with `df1$Value` next to the `Tree facet`? Such as:

[image]

**df1 data :**

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(5L, 15L, 29L, 18L, 24L, 21L, 
13L, 11L, 8L, 25L, 23L, 9L, 16L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 20L, 27L, 30L, 17L, 
14L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 28L, 10L, 12L, 26L, 19L), .Label = c("t1", 
"t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18", 
"t19", "t2", "t20", "t21", "t22", "t23", "t24", "t25", "t26", 
"t27", "t28", "t29", "t3", "t30", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", 
"t9"), class = "factor"), location = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CZ", 
"GZ", "HK"), class = "factor"), Value = c(NA, 10L, NA, 12L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45L, 89L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 80L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with the ggtree package or it's syntax but some trial and error shows that you can simply expand with `geom_text` and `geom_bar` to get a table-like facet.

```r
library(ggtree)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

df1 <- structure(
  list(id = structure(
    c(5L, 15L, 29L, 18L, 24L, 21L, 
      13L, 11L, 8L, 25L, 23L, 9L, 16L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 20L, 27L, 30L, 17L, 
      14L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 28L, 10L, 12L, 26L, 19L), 
    .Label = c("t1", 
               "t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18", 
               "t19", "t2", "t20", "t21", "t22", "t23", "t24", "t25", "t26", 
               "t27", "t28", "t29", "t3", "t30", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", 
               "t9"), class = "factor"), 
    location = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
                           1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
                           1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), 
                         .Label = c("CZ", "GZ", "HK"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(NA, 10L, NA, 12L, NA, 
              NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45L, 89L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
              NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 80L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                      -30L))

tr <- rtree(30)
p <- ggtree(tr)
#df1<- your_example_data
p1 <- p %<+% df1 + geom_tippoint(aes(color=location))
d2 <- data.frame(id=tr$tip.label, val=rnorm(30, sd=3))

# Here be the extra bits
p11 <- facet_plot(p1, panel = "new_facet", geom = geom_tile,
                  aes(x = 0), fill = NA, colour = "black", data = df1)
p12 <- facet_plot(p11, panel = "new_facet", geom = geom_text,
                  aes(x = 0, label = df1$Value), data = df1)

# Note p12 goes into p2
p2 <- facet_plot(p12, panel="dot", data=d2, geom=geom_point, aes(x=val), color='firebrick') + theme_tree2()
d3 <- data.frame(id = rep(tr$tip.label, each=2),
                 value = abs(rnorm(60, mean=100, sd=50)),
                 category = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 30))
p3 <- facet_plot(p2, panel = 'Stacked Barplot', data = d3, 
                 geom = geom_barh, 
                 mapping = aes(x = value, fill = as.factor(category)), 
                 stat='identity' )
p3
#> Warning: Removed 25 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: wooow thank you very mucch for your help ^.^